# Resolvent of semicircle law

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, random-matrices

I am trying to approximate the Stieltjes transform of the semicircle law.  In particular, it is known that the Stieltjes transform m(z), for z in the upper half plane, is exactly

$$
m(z) = \frac{-z + \sqrt{z^2 - 4}}{2}
$$
I would like to show that

$$
Im(m(z)) \sim \sqrt{K + y}
$$
for $z = x+ iy$, $K = ||x|-2|$ and $|x| \leq 2$. ( $a \sim b$ means there exist constants $c, C$ such that $cb \leq a \leq Cb$.) 
Also,
$$
Im(m(z)) \sim \frac{y}{\sqrt{K + y}}
$$
when $x \geq 2$.

I have tried Taylor expansions with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that $\sqrt{a + ib} = p + iq$ with $p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + a}$ and $q = \frac{sign(b)}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - a}$.

Comment: Actually, this was the first step I tried and was unable to get the correct approximations.